# Linq: get my all my sub objects base on property

Tags: c#, linq

So i have this classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Application> Applications { get; set; }
}  


public class Application
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
 }


public class Folder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected{ get; set; }

    public FileInfo[] Tests { get; set; }
}
```

And i have this `ObservableCollection` collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<Product> products;

public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
{
    get { return products; }
    set
    {
        products = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And my `ListView` have this `CheckBox` that changed this Folder `IsSelected` property and i want to get all the selected folders via `Linq`:

```
var selectedFolders = Products.Where(x => x.Applications = ...);
```

Any seggestions ?

Comment: Do you expect `selectedFolders` to be a `IEnumerable<Folder>`?

Comment: Yes.. this is collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___) calls to flatten an `ObservableCollection<Product>` into an `IEnumerable<Folder>`. Then you can use `Where`:

```
var selectedFolders = Products.SelectMany(x => Applications)
                                .SelectMany(x => x.Folders)
                                .Where(x => x.IsSelected);
```